# What is wrong with the code I wrote?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def insert(lst, idx, elem):
    lst = lst[:idx] + [elem] + lst[idx:]

list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
insert(list1, 5, 5)

list2 = ['0', '1', '0']
insert(list2, 0, '1')

for example, list1 should be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for example, list2 should be ['1', '0', '1', '0']
Edit: for example, insert([1, 2, 3], 1, 0) should be None
```

What is wrong with my code? What should be the correct answer?

```
I have been getting:
list1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
list2 ['0', '1', '0']
```

Comment: Read this: http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/. You are reassigning `lst`, so the original is not modified.

Comment: How to do this question if you do not write x = insert(list1, 5, 5), y = insert(list2, 0, '1') and print(x) print(y)? Just modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value of `lst`:

```
def insert(lst, idx, elem):
    lst = lst[:idx] + [elem] + lst[idx:]
    return lst

list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]
x = insert(list1, 5, 5)

list2 = ['0', '1', '0']
y = insert(list2, 0, '1')

print(x)
print(y)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
['1', '0', '1', '0']
```

Comment: How to do this question if you do not write x = insert(list1, 5, 5), y = insert(list2, 0, '1') and print(x) print(y)? Just modify the code.

Comment: If you want to print the `return` result then use `print(insert(list1, 5, 5))` — if not `insert(list1, 5, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I assume that this question wants you to modify the list in place.

When you use slicing, there will actually be new copies created instead of modifying the list in place. Hence, when you try to call `insert()` and `print(x)` you will get `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]`

What you can do is to create a copy of the array using `[:]` --> `lst[:] = lst[:idx] + [elem] + lst[idx:]`

you don't need to return `lst` as the test case actually tests for whether lst is original array.